# How can I work out this view?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views

- `List -> l_user` I have a `List` node that has a user-reference field (`l_user`).
- `Story -> s-user` I then have `Story` nodes that also have a user-reference field (`s_user`).
- There is no direct connection between `List` and `Story`.

I want to add a view to `List` that lists all the stories that reference the same user that `list` references. Basically something like `SELECT stories WHERE story.s_user = this list.l_user` and `l_user` is the user referenced in the list this view is on.

So far the view is being filtered by `node:type story` but I'm not sure what to use (arguments/filter, etc) to link the `story s_user` to the `list l_user`.

Is this doable with Views?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a Views argument. What you're trying to do is filter that list by user, and you get the user to filter by from the node you're currently on (or more specifically, the node's user reference field). So what you'll need to do is supply Views with an argument that is equal to the node's user reference field.

To do that, set up your view as normal and as if you were showing every user's node. So you might have a view that's like:

- Page 1 (by User 1)
- Page 2 (by User 1)
- Page 3 (by User 2)
- Page 4 (by User 2)
- Page 5 (by User 1)

Where the user is a user reference field on each page called *Story user reference*.

Now, under *Arguments* add an argument for *Content: Story user reference*. Now, the view will only show nodes that are posted by the user specified in the argument. The problem is, in a block, there is no argument to specify: you need to provide a default argument.

Still on the argument configuration pane for  *Content: Story user reference*, select *Provide default argument* under *Action to take if argument is not present*. You'll get a variety of options, but none of them are what you're looking for: the current node's user reference field.

So you'll need to use the *PHP code* action and use the following code:

```
$node = node_load(arg(1));
return $node->field_list_user[0]['uid'];
```

This loads a node based on the node ID retrieved from the current page's path and returns the node's user reference field (change `field_list_user` to the name of the user reference field on the list nodes).

So if I'm on node 17 whose user reference field states user 4, the argument that'll be passed to the view is 4. The view will then only show nodes in the view who have user references that are also 4.

Save your view, create a block display, and place it wherever you want. When you visit a node page with a user reference field, the block will populate with the referenced user's nodes.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer combined with Scott Reynen's answer helped. But this one was more thorough so it deserves the check mark.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest getting all of the user references from the list node and passing those into a views argument. So your code would look something like this (untested):

```
$user_ids = array();
foreach ($list_node->l_user as $user_reference) {
  $user_ids[] = $user_reference['uid'];
}
$view = views_get_view('list_view');
return $view->preview('block_1', array(implode(',', $user_ids));
```

That assumes you have a view named 'list_view' with a display named 'block_1' (you can see the machine name when you hover over the display). That display needs to be a node view with a filter of node type 'story' and an argument of content user_l set to take multiple values. There's almost certainly a bug in that code, but I know the general concept works, as I've done it several times before.

Comment: Thanks very much. Your answer combined with Mark Trapp's answer helped.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this you need to download NodeReferrer. http://drupal.org/project/nodereferrer

It provides a counter part to CCK's node reference field.

Then you can call the field "Node referrer" in your View.

Comment: But in the view itself, how do I treat the "node referrer" field? as an argument or filter or something else?

Comment: i assume you want all stories connect to a user? is the reference field located in the content-type user or story?

Comment: Both `story` and `list` contain a field that stores `user`. I'm trying to add the view to `list` however, and the view should contain only `stories` whose `user` match the `user` on the list.