# Can't work a view, how to bypass it and code it in php instead

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views

I'm new to drupal, and having a tough time getting a view to work ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474114/how-can-i-work-out-this-drupal-view)).

Since I can't figure out how to do this with Views, and since getting this done in code is usually a piece of code, is there a way I could bypass the Views UI interface entirely and set the view with normal MySQL code?

Comment: Don't create duplicate questions: update your original question instead.

Comment: @Mark Look closer. The 2 questions are very different. One is about using views and the other is about using MySQL to avoid using views.

Comment: @Kamo he's trying to accomplish the same thing (this question wholly depends on the previous question), and because he hadn't gotten an answer on the original question, he's asking the same question but with a different suggestion as to how to start. It's ultimately the same question with one answer: he's better served by updating his original question with things he's tried to get the result he wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[hook_views_query_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/function/hook_views_query_alter)allows you to alter the query run by views. [db_query](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/db_query/6) is how you do custom queries, though Drupal's database structure isn't fixed, so you should look at something like [this article](http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/safely-querying-cck-data-types) if you're going to do that. I think your original question has a simpler solution, though, which I'll leave there.

Answer (score 1):

You might try this module: http://drupal.org/project/qviews